# UDDTIO reading: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I'm trying to put together a minimal example for performing user-defined derived type input output in Fortran using ifort compiler version 15. The code posted below is able to read and write accordingly, however after "read" is done executing and while control is being returned to the main program the following error occurs:

```
(61586,0x7fff7e4dd300) malloc: *** error for object 0x10fa7bac4: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The UDDTIO routines are called in the program as:

```
module mod_test

    implicit none

    type, public :: class_test
        integer :: foo
    contains
        procedure, private :: write_test
        procedure, private :: read_test
        generic :: write(formatted) => write_test
        generic :: read(formatted)  => read_test
    end type class_test

contains

    subroutine     write_test(dtv, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
        !
        implicit none
        !
        class(class_test), intent(in) :: dtv
        integer     , intent(in)    :: unit
        character(*), intent(in)    :: iotype
        integer     , intent(in)    :: v_list(:)
        integer     , intent(out)   :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg
        !
        iostat = 0
        !
        write(unit,'(a,/)') '<foo>'
        write(unit,*) dtv%foo
        write(unit,'(/)')
        write(unit,'(a,/)') '</foo>'
        !
    end subroutine write_test

    subroutine     read_test(dtv, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
        !
        implicit none
        !
        class(class_test), intent(inout) :: dtv
        integer     , intent(in)    :: unit
        character(*), intent(in)    :: iotype
        integer     , intent(in)    :: v_list(:)
        integer     , intent(out)   :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg
        !
        read(unit,'(/)')
        read(unit,*) dtv%foo
        read(unit,'(/)')
        read(unit,'(/)')
        write(*,*) 'z'
    end subroutine read_test

end module mod_test

program main

    use mod_test

    implicit none

    type(class_test) :: test

    test%foo = 5

    write(*,*) 'writing'
    open(unit=1, file='write.out', status='replace', action='write')
        write(unit=1,fmt=*) test
    close(unit=1)

    write(*,*) 'reading'
    open(unit=1, file='write.out', status='old', action='read')
        read(unit=1,fmt=*) test
    close(unit=1)

    write(*,*) 'end'

end program main
```

The problem seems to be with the line break statements '(/)'.
Adding iostat=-1 to the read routine seems "solve" the problem. But why?

Answer (score 2):

UDDTIO procedures are required to define the `iostat` dummy argument, so that the compiler's runtime can test for error and take the appropriate action.

Note that UDDTIO is a relatively recently implemented feature for that compiler.  You need to be using the latest possible compiler version.

If I define the `iostat` dummy argument appropriately in the read and write UDDTIO procedures, your code runs for me with the current 17.0 beta.

Further UDDTIO issues should be fixed in the initial release of 17.0, which can't be too far away.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I will update the compiler. I'd like to note that with my compiler version, adding iostat=0 still causes the error. Only iostat=-1 is helps.